# JS: что делает этот код?

Tags: javascript, обфускация

Взломали сайт на modx. В PHP скриптах кое-как разобрался, а с JS возникли проблемы.

Что делает следующий код?

```
var _0x191a=["\x6F\x20\x75\x3D\x31\x4E\x28\x31\x30\x2E\x49\x2E\x4B\x29\x3B\x6F\x20\x31\x73\x3D\x31\x4E\x28\x31\x30\x2E\x49\x2E\x33\x34\x2E\x32\x5A\x28\x31\x29\x29\x2E\x31\x31\x28\x27\x26\x27\x29\x2E\x33\x6D\x28\x33\x20\x32\x51\x28\x61\x2C\x62\x29\x7B\x62\x3D\x62\x2E\x31\x31\x28\x27\x3D\x27\x29\x3B\x37\x28\x61\x5B\x62\x5B\x30\x5D\x5D\x29\x7B\x37\x28\x32\x68\x28\x61\x5B\x62\x5B\x30\x5D\x5D\x29\x29\x7B\x61\x5B\x62\x5B\x30\x5D\x5D\x2E\x31\x39\x28\x62\x5B\x31\x5D\x29\x7D\x4E\x7B\x6F\x20\x31\x6A\x3D\x5B\x5D\x3B\x31\x6A\x2E\x31\x39\x28\x61\x5B\x62\x5B\x30\x5D\x5D\x29\x3B\x31\x6A\x2E\x31\x39\x28\x62\x5B\x31\x5D\x29\x3B\x61\x5B\x62\x5B\x30\x5D\x5D\x3D\x31\x6A\x7D\x7D\x4E\x7B\x61\x5B\x62\x5B\x30\x5D\x5D\x3D\x62\x5B\x31\x5D\x7D\x69\x20\x61\x7D\x2C\x7B\x7D\x29\x3B\x33\x20\x42\x28\x29\x7B\x31\x4F\x3D\x49\x2E\x4B\x2E\x31\x31\x28\x27\x3F\x27\x29\x3B\x69\x20\x31\x4F\x5B\x30\x5D\x2B\x27\x3F\x68\x3D\x27\x2B\x31\x73\x5B\x27\x68\x27\x5D\x2B\x27\x26\x61\x3D\x27\x2B\x31\x73\x5B\x27\x61\x27\x5D\x7D\x33\x20\x32\x4E\x28\x38\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x4D\x20\x2E\x76\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x34\x28\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x6F\x20\x31\x33\x3D\x24\x28\x6E\x29\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x32\x4B\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x29\x3B\x31\x33\x3D\x31\x33\x2E\x31\x53\x28\x29\x3B\x37\x28\x31\x33\x2E\x32\x4A\x28\x38\x2E\x31\x53\x28\x29\x29\x3C\x30\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x6E\x29\x2E\x4C\x28\x29\x7D\x4E\x7B\x24\x28\x6E\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x7D\x35\x3D\x7B\x32\x46\x3A\x7B\x7D\x2C\x7A\x3A\x7B\x7D\x2C\x54\x3A\x33\x28\x31\x56\x29\x7B\x6B\x3D\x27\x27\x3B\x37\x28\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x6B\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x21\x3D\x27\x27\x29\x7B\x74\x3D\x31\x42\x28\x27\x28\x27\x2B\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x6B\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x2B\x27\x29\x27\x29\x3B\x6B\x3D\x74\x2E\x6B\x7D\x3B\x6D\x3D\x7B\x6B\x3A\x6B\x2C\x32\x47\x3A\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x32\x48\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x7D\x3B\x69\x20\x24\x2E\x54\x28\x31\x56\x2C\x6D\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x37\x3A\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x2E\x55\x28\x7B\x75\x3A\x27\x31\x52\x3A\x2F\x2F\x27\x2B\x49\x2E\x32\x49\x2B\x27\x2F\x32\x4F\x2F\x32\x6D\x2F\x35\x2F\x31\x37\x2E\x31\x57\x27\x2C\x31\x6E\x3A\x79\x2C\x32\x3A\x7B\x32\x50\x3A\x27\x32\x56\x27\x7D\x2C\x39\x3A\x27\x31\x70\x27\x2C\x31\x66\x3A\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x31\x30\x2E\x49\x2E\x32\x57\x28\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x58\x3A\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x37\x28\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x6B\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x21\x3D\x27\x27\x29\x7B\x35\x2E\x41\x28\x27\x32\x45\x27\x2C\x7B\x27\x32\x54\x27\x3A\x27\x31\x27\x7D\x2C\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x37\x28\x32\x2E\x31\x64\x29\x7B\x35\x2E\x31\x38\x28\x32\x29\x7D\x3B\x35\x2E\x31\x68\x28\x32\x2E\x31\x64\x29\x7D\x29\x7D\x7D\x2C\x31\x68\x3A\x33\x28\x31\x4C\x29\x7B\x37\x28\x31\x4C\x29\x7B\x74\x3D\x31\x42\x28\x27\x28\x27\x2B\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x6B\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x2B\x27\x29\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x31\x67\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x74\x2E\x31\x67\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x31\x46\x27\x29\x2E\x4C\x28\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x32\x52\x27\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x29\x7D\x7D\x2C\x32\x53\x3A\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x2E\x55\x28\x7B\x75\x3A\x42\x28\x29\x2B\x22\x26\x4F\x3D\x32\x59\x22\x2C\x39\x3A\x27\x31\x79\x27\x2C\x32\x3A\x7B\x74\x3A\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x6B\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x66\x3A\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x31\x30\x2E\x49\x2E\x4B\x3D\x31\x30\x2E\x49\x2E\x4B\x7D\x7D\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x46\x3A\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x31\x43\x20\x2E\x31\x4B\x27\x29\x2E\x4C\x28\x29\x3B\x6F\x20\x74\x3D\x7B\x7D\x3B\x35\x2E\x41\x28\x27\x31\x46\x27\x2C\x7B\x36\x3A\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x36\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x2C\x31\x5A\x3A\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x31\x5A\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x7D\x2C\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x37\x28\x32\x2E\x31\x64\x29\x7B\x74\x2E\x6B\x3D\x32\x2E\x6B\x3B\x74\x2E\x31\x67\x3D\x32\x2E\x31\x67\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x6B\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x32\x6F\x2E\x32\x6E\x28\x74\x29\x29\x3B\x35\x2E\x31\x38\x28\x32\x29\x3B\x35\x2E\x31\x68\x28\x32\x37\x29\x3B\x24\x2E\x55\x28\x7B\x75\x3A\x42\x28\x29\x2B\x22\x26\x4F\x3D\x32\x73\x22\x2C\x39\x3A\x27\x31\x79\x27\x2C\x32\x3A\x7B\x74\x3A\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x6B\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x7D\x4E\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x31\x43\x20\x2E\x31\x4B\x27\x29\x2E\x32\x79\x28\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x6A\x3A\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x2E\x41\x28\x27\x32\x41\x27\x2C\x7B\x27\x31\x65\x27\x3A\x27\x31\x27\x7D\x2C\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x35\x2E\x48\x3D\x32\x2E\x32\x78\x3B\x35\x2E\x32\x77\x3D\x32\x2E\x48\x3B\x35\x2E\x32\x69\x28\x32\x2E\x48\x29\x3B\x6F\x20\x68\x3D\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x31\x74\x27\x29\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x31\x47\x27\x29\x2E\x32\x63\x28\x29\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x61\x27\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x68\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x78\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x68\x29\x3B\x35\x2E\x31\x32\x28\x35\x2E\x48\x5B\x68\x5D\x29\x3B\x37\x28\x32\x2E\x70\x21\x3D\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x70\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x29\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x32\x76\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x32\x2E\x70\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x32\x75\x27\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x29\x7D\x37\x28\x32\x2E\x31\x65\x29\x7B\x35\x2E\x31\x68\x28\x32\x2E\x31\x65\x2E\x31\x64\x29\x3B\x35\x2E\x31\x38\x28\x32\x2E\x31\x65\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x3B\x35\x2E\x7A\x3D\x31\x42\x28\x27\x28\x27\x2B\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x7A\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x2B\x27\x29\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x61\x2E\x4A\x2D\x31\x50\x2C\x61\x2E\x4A\x2D\x31\x37\x27\x29\x2E\x51\x28\x27\x57\x27\x2C\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x37\x28\x33\x76\x28\x24\x28\x6E\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x31\x4D\x27\x29\x29\x29\x35\x2E\x46\x28\x6E\x29\x3B\x69\x20\x79\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x61\x2E\x4A\x2D\x46\x27\x29\x2E\x51\x28\x27\x57\x27\x2C\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x2E\x46\x28\x6E\x29\x3B\x69\x20\x79\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x4A\x2D\x33\x73\x27\x29\x2E\x51\x28\x27\x57\x27\x2C\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x63\x3D\x27\x3C\x31\x47\x20\x32\x2D\x68\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x24\x28\x6E\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x68\x27\x29\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x24\x28\x6E\x29\x2E\x78\x28\x29\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x2E\x33\x74\x2D\x48\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x4D\x28\x29\x2B\x27\x3C\x61\x20\x4B\x3D\x22\x23\x22\x3E\x58\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x31\x47\x3E\x27\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x31\x43\x20\x52\x27\x29\x2E\x32\x34\x28\x63\x29\x3B\x69\x20\x79\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x31\x74\x20\x61\x27\x29\x2E\x51\x28\x27\x57\x27\x2C\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x78\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x24\x28\x6E\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x68\x27\x29\x29\x3B\x35\x2E\x31\x32\x28\x35\x2E\x48\x5B\x24\x28\x6E\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x68\x27\x29\x5D\x2C\x24\x28\x6E\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x63\x27\x29\x29\x3B\x69\x20\x79\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x32\x36\x20\x61\x27\x29\x2E\x51\x28\x27\x57\x27\x2C\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x78\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x24\x28\x6E\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x29\x29\x3B\x35\x2E\x31\x6C\x28\x7B\x7D\x2C\x35\x2E\x32\x6C\x29\x3B\x69\x20\x79\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x33\x70\x20\x3A\x33\x77\x27\x29\x2E\x33\x45\x28\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x2E\x31\x71\x28\x7B\x7D\x2C\x35\x2E\x31\x32\x29\x7D\x29\x7D\x2C\x46\x3A\x33\x28\x73\x29\x7B\x6F\x20\x47\x3D\x24\x28\x73\x29\x2E\x44\x28\x27\x2E\x76\x27\x29\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x2E\x33\x46\x27\x29\x3B\x6F\x20\x50\x3D\x24\x28\x73\x29\x2E\x44\x28\x27\x2E\x76\x27\x29\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x22\x42\x22\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x3B\x35\x2E\x41\x28\x27\x33\x44\x27\x2C\x7B\x68\x3A\x24\x28\x73\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x68\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x7D\x29\x3B\x37\x28\x24\x28\x73\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x31\x45\x27\x29\x3D\x3D\x22\x33\x43\x22\x29\x7B\x6F\x20\x31\x4A\x3D\x42\x28\x29\x2B\x22\x26\x4F\x3D\x46\x26\x31\x59\x3D\x22\x2B\x24\x28\x73\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x68\x27\x29\x2B\x22\x26\x36\x3D\x22\x2B\x24\x28\x73\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x36\x27\x29\x2B\x22\x26\x50\x3D\x22\x2B\x50\x3B\x24\x2E\x33\x42\x2E\x33\x78\x28\x7B\x4B\x3A\x31\x4A\x2C\x39\x3A\x27\x33\x79\x27\x7D\x29\x7D\x4E\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x4D\x20\x2E\x76\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x48\x28\x27\x31\x55\x27\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x73\x29\x2E\x44\x28\x27\x2E\x76\x27\x29\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x2E\x31\x36\x27\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x29\x3B\x24\x2E\x55\x28\x7B\x75\x3A\x42\x28\x29\x2B\x22\x26\x31\x45\x3D\x32\x30\x26\x4F\x3D\x46\x26\x31\x59\x3D\x22\x2B\x24\x28\x73\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x68\x27\x29\x2B\x22\x26\x36\x3D\x22\x2B\x24\x28\x73\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x2D\x36\x27\x29\x2C\x39\x3A\x27\x31\x79\x27\x2C\x32\x3A\x7B\x31\x45\x3A\x27\x32\x30\x27\x2C\x50\x3A\x50\x7D\x2C\x31\x66\x3A\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x47\x2E\x44\x28\x27\x2E\x76\x27\x29\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x2E\x31\x36\x27\x29\x2E\x4C\x28\x29\x3B\x47\x2E\x31\x51\x28\x27\x31\x49\x27\x2C\x27\x33\x36\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x54\x28\x7B\x31\x58\x3A\x31\x7D\x2C\x33\x37\x2C\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x47\x2E\x33\x38\x28\x33\x35\x29\x2E\x31\x54\x28\x7B\x31\x58\x3A\x30\x7D\x2C\x33\x30\x2C\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x47\x2E\x31\x51\x28\x27\x31\x49\x27\x2C\x27\x33\x32\x27\x29\x7D\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x47\x2E\x44\x28\x27\x2E\x76\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x72\x28\x27\x4A\x2D\x46\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x72\x28\x27\x4A\x2D\x31\x37\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x48\x28\x27\x4A\x2D\x31\x50\x27\x29\x3B\x47\x2E\x44\x28\x27\x2E\x76\x27\x29\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x2E\x33\x39\x27\x29\x2E\x4C\x28\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x4D\x20\x2E\x76\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x72\x28\x27\x31\x55\x27\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x7D\x7D\x2C\x41\x3A\x33\x28\x4F\x2C\x6D\x2C\x45\x29\x7B\x6D\x3D\x35\x2E\x54\x28\x6D\x29\x3B\x24\x2E\x55\x28\x7B\x75\x3A\x27\x31\x52\x3A\x2F\x2F\x33\x67\x2E\x33\x66\x2D\x33\x62\x2E\x33\x63\x2F\x31\x70\x2E\x31\x57\x3F\x31\x70\x3D\x27\x2B\x4F\x2C\x31\x6E\x3A\x79\x2C\x32\x3A\x6D\x2C\x33\x65\x3A\x22\x33\x72\x22\x2C\x39\x3A\x27\x33\x64\x27\x2C\x31\x6E\x3A\x79\x2C\x31\x66\x3A\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x45\x28\x32\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x31\x3A\x33\x28\x6D\x2C\x45\x29\x7B\x35\x2E\x41\x28\x27\x32\x31\x27\x2C\x6D\x2C\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x45\x28\x32\x29\x7D\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x71\x3A\x33\x28\x6D\x2C\x45\x29\x7B\x35\x2E\x41\x28\x27\x31\x71\x27\x2C\x24\x2E\x54\x28\x6D\x2C\x7B\x78\x3A\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x78\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x2C\x31\x69\x3A\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x31\x69\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x2C\x31\x63\x3A\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x31\x63\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x7D\x29\x2C\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x45\x28\x32\x29\x7D\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x6C\x3A\x33\x28\x6D\x2C\x45\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x4D\x20\x3E\x20\x20\x2E\x31\x36\x27\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x29\x3B\x35\x2E\x41\x28\x27\x31\x6C\x27\x2C\x24\x2E\x54\x28\x6D\x2C\x7B\x78\x3A\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x78\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x2C\x31\x69\x3A\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x31\x69\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x2C\x31\x63\x3A\x24\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x31\x63\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x38\x28\x29\x7D\x29\x2C\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x45\x28\x32\x29\x7D\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x69\x3A\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x31\x74\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x27\x3C\x52\x3E\x27\x2B\x35\x2E\x31\x76\x28\x32\x2C\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x63\x20\x23\x33\x6A\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x29\x29\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x52\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x32\x3A\x33\x28\x32\x2C\x63\x29\x7B\x63\x3D\x63\x7C\x7C\x27\x32\x65\x27\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x4D\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x35\x2E\x31\x6F\x28\x32\x2C\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x63\x20\x23\x33\x69\x27\x2B\x63\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x29\x2C\x63\x29\x29\x7D\x2C\x32\x6C\x3A\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x4D\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x35\x2E\x31\x6F\x28\x32\x2C\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x63\x20\x23\x33\x68\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x29\x29\x2B\x27\x3C\x43\x20\x33\x61\x3D\x22\x31\x36\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x43\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x2C\x31\x38\x3A\x33\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x37\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x32\x36\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x27\x3C\x52\x3E\x27\x2B\x35\x2E\x31\x76\x28\x32\x2E\x48\x2C\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x63\x20\x23\x33\x33\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x29\x29\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x52\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x7D\x2C\x31\x6F\x3A\x33\x28\x32\x2C\x63\x2C\x32\x35\x29\x7B\x6F\x20\x66\x3D\x27\x27\x3B\x37\x28\x32\x29\x7B\x24\x2E\x31\x34\x28\x32\x2C\x33\x28\x31\x78\x2C\x72\x29\x7B\x32\x67\x7B\x66\x3D\x66\x2B\x35\x2E\x32\x39\x28\x63\x2C\x72\x2C\x32\x35\x29\x7D\x32\x32\x28\x65\x29\x7B\x32\x33\x2E\x32\x38\x28\x65\x2E\x36\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x7D\x4E\x7B\x7D\x69\x20\x66\x7D\x2C\x31\x76\x3A\x33\x28\x32\x2C\x63\x29\x7B\x6F\x20\x66\x3D\x27\x27\x3B\x24\x2E\x31\x34\x28\x32\x2C\x33\x28\x31\x78\x2C\x72\x29\x7B\x32\x67\x7B\x66\x3D\x66\x2B\x35\x2E\x32\x62\x28\x63\x2C\x72\x29\x7D\x32\x32\x28\x65\x29\x7B\x32\x33\x2E\x32\x38\x28\x65\x2E\x36\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x3B\x69\x20\x66\x7D\x2C\x32\x39\x3A\x33\x28\x71\x2C\x34\x2C\x63\x29\x7B\x63\x3D\x63\x7C\x7C\x27\x32\x65\x27\x3B\x34\x2E\x31\x77\x3D\x27\x33\x6B\x27\x3B\x34\x2E\x32\x64\x3D\x34\x2E\x75\x3D\x3D\x27\x27\x3F\x27\x32\x64\x27\x3A\x27\x33\x6C\x27\x3B\x34\x2E\x70\x3D\x34\x2E\x70\x7C\x7C\x27\x27\x3B\x34\x2E\x56\x3D\x34\x2E\x56\x7C\x7C\x27\x27\x3B\x37\x28\x24\x2E\x33\x41\x28\x34\x2E\x75\x29\x29\x7B\x31\x7A\x3D\x5B\x5D\x3B\x31\x44\x3D\x34\x2E\x75\x2E\x33\x7A\x3B\x24\x2E\x31\x34\x28\x31\x44\x2C\x33\x28\x31\x78\x2C\x72\x29\x7B\x31\x7A\x2E\x31\x39\x28\x27\x3C\x31\x41\x20\x72\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x72\x2E\x50\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x72\x2E\x70\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x31\x41\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x37\x28\x21\x34\x2E\x70\x29\x34\x2E\x70\x3D\x72\x2E\x70\x3B\x37\x28\x21\x34\x2E\x56\x29\x34\x2E\x56\x3D\x72\x2E\x56\x3B\x24\x71\x3D\x24\x28\x71\x29\x3B\x24\x71\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x42\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x32\x34\x28\x31\x7A\x2E\x31\x6D\x28\x27\x27\x29\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x71\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x31\x41\x27\x29\x2E\x32\x63\x28\x29\x2E\x33\x6F\x28\x27\x33\x6E\x27\x2C\x32\x37\x29\x3B\x37\x28\x31\x44\x2E\x31\x75\x3D\x3D\x31\x29\x7B\x24\x71\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x5B\x36\x3D\x42\x5D\x27\x29\x2E\x4C\x28\x29\x7D\x71\x3D\x24\x71\x2E\x33\x71\x28\x27\x3C\x43\x3E\x3C\x2F\x43\x3E\x27\x29\x2E\x78\x28\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x29\x7D\x37\x28\x34\x2E\x39\x29\x7B\x34\x2E\x39\x3D\x34\x2E\x39\x3D\x3D\x27\x33\x75\x27\x3F\x27\x32\x55\x27\x3A\x34\x2E\x39\x3B\x34\x2E\x39\x3D\x34\x2E\x39\x3D\x3D\x27\x32\x72\x27\x3F\x27\x32\x6D\x27\x3A\x34\x2E\x39\x3B\x34\x2E\x39\x3D\x34\x2E\x39\x3D\x3D\x27\x32\x44\x27\x3F\x27\x32\x7A\x27\x3A\x34\x2E\x39\x3B\x37\x28\x35\x2E\x7A\x5B\x34\x2E\x39\x5D\x29\x7B\x37\x28\x35\x2E\x7A\x5B\x34\x2E\x39\x5D\x5B\x34\x2E\x31\x6B\x5D\x29\x7B\x34\x2E\x32\x43\x3D\x35\x2E\x7A\x5B\x34\x2E\x39\x5D\x5B\x34\x2E\x31\x6B\x5D\x3B\x37\x28\x35\x2E\x7A\x5B\x34\x2E\x39\x5D\x5B\x34\x2E\x31\x6B\x5D\x3C\x34\x2E\x70\x29\x7B\x34\x2E\x31\x77\x3D\x27\x32\x42\x27\x7D\x37\x28\x35\x2E\x7A\x5B\x34\x2E\x39\x5D\x5B\x34\x2E\x31\x6B\x5D\x3D\x3D\x34\x2E\x70\x29\x7B\x34\x2E\x31\x77\x3D\x27\x32\x70\x27\x7D\x7D\x7D\x7D\x66\x3D\x71\x2E\x32\x61\x28\x2F\x25\x5C\x77\x2B\x25\x2F\x67\x2C\x33\x28\x31\x35\x29\x7B\x69\x20\x34\x5B\x31\x35\x2E\x31\x31\x28\x27\x25\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x6D\x28\x27\x27\x29\x5D\x7C\x7C\x27\x27\x7D\x29\x3B\x59\x3D\x34\x2E\x31\x61\x3B\x37\x28\x63\x3D\x3D\x27\x32\x74\x27\x29\x59\x3D\x34\x2E\x32\x71\x3B\x37\x28\x34\x2E\x31\x61\x29\x66\x3D\x24\x28\x27\x3C\x43\x20\x68\x3D\x22\x31\x62\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x66\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x43\x3E\x27\x29\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x59\x27\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x6B\x27\x2C\x59\x29\x2E\x44\x28\x27\x23\x31\x62\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x29\x3B\x69\x20\x66\x7D\x2C\x32\x62\x3A\x33\x28\x71\x2C\x34\x29\x7B\x6F\x20\x66\x3D\x71\x2E\x32\x61\x28\x2F\x25\x5C\x77\x2B\x25\x2F\x67\x2C\x33\x28\x31\x35\x29\x7B\x69\x20\x34\x5B\x31\x35\x2E\x31\x31\x28\x27\x25\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x6D\x28\x27\x27\x29\x5D\x7C\x7C\x27\x27\x7D\x29\x3B\x37\x28\x34\x2E\x31\x61\x29\x66\x3D\x24\x28\x27\x3C\x43\x20\x68\x3D\x22\x31\x62\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x66\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x43\x3E\x27\x29\x2E\x6C\x28\x27\x59\x27\x29\x2E\x6A\x28\x27\x32\x6B\x27\x2C\x34\x2E\x31\x61\x29\x2E\x44\x28\x27\x23\x31\x62\x27\x29\x2E\x64\x28\x29\x3B\x69\x20\x66\x7D\x2C\x32\x68\x3A\x33\x28\x5A\x29\x7B\x69\x20\x5A\x26\x26\x21\x28\x5A\x2E\x32\x4D\x28\x27\x31\x75\x27\x29\x29\x26\x26\x32\x66\x20\x5A\x3D\x3D\x3D\x27\x32\x4C\x27\x26\x26\x32\x66\x20\x5A\x2E\x31\x75\x3D\x3D\x3D\x27\x33\x31\x27\x7D\x7D\x3B\x24\x28\x33\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x2E\x32\x6A\x28\x29\x7D\x29","\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x7C\x7C\x64\x61\x74\x61\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x61\x72\x72\x61\x79\x7C\x73\x74\x6F\x72\x65\x7C\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x76\x61\x6C\x7C\x74\x79\x70\x65\x7C\x7C\x7C\x74\x70\x6C\x7C\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x7C\x7C\x6F\x75\x74\x7C\x7C\x69\x64\x7C\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x7C\x61\x74\x74\x72\x7C\x68\x61\x73\x68\x7C\x66\x69\x6E\x64\x7C\x70\x61\x72\x61\x6D\x7C\x74\x68\x69\x73\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x76\x65\x72\x73\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x73\x74\x72\x7C\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65\x7C\x65\x6C\x6D\x7C\x72\x65\x73\x7C\x75\x72\x6C\x7C\x63\x61\x74\x61\x6C\x6F\x67\x5F\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x7C\x7C\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x66\x61\x6C\x73\x65\x7C\x74\x79\x70\x65\x73\x7C\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x7C\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x7C\x64\x69\x76\x7C\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65\x73\x74\x7C\x63\x61\x6C\x6C\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x7C\x69\x6E\x73\x74\x61\x6C\x6C\x7C\x65\x6C\x7C\x63\x61\x74\x65\x67\x6F\x72\x79\x7C\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x7C\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x68\x69\x64\x65\x7C\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x7C\x65\x6C\x73\x65\x7C\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x66\x69\x6C\x65\x7C\x6C\x69\x76\x65\x7C\x75\x6C\x7C\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x7C\x65\x78\x74\x65\x6E\x64\x7C\x61\x6A\x61\x78\x7C\x64\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x7C\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x41\x72\x72\x61\x79\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x7C\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74\x7C\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x7C\x73\x65\x61\x72\x63\x68\x5F\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x65\x61\x63\x68\x7C\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x68\x6F\x6C\x64\x65\x72\x7C\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x7C\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x55\x73\x65\x72\x43\x61\x74\x65\x67\x6F\x72\x79\x7C\x70\x75\x73\x68\x7C\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x74\x6D\x70\x6C\x7C\x64\x69\x72\x7C\x72\x65\x73\x75\x6C\x74\x7C\x75\x73\x65\x72\x7C\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73\x7C\x75\x73\x65\x72\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x55\x73\x65\x72\x46\x6F\x72\x6D\x73\x7C\x73\x6F\x72\x74\x7C\x61\x72\x72\x7C\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x5F\x69\x6E\x5F\x6D\x6F\x64\x78\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x5F\x6F\x77\x6E\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x7C\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E\x7C\x63\x61\x63\x68\x65\x7C\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x7C\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x5F\x47\x45\x54\x7C\x63\x61\x74\x65\x67\x6F\x72\x79\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x7C\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7C\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x31\x7C\x63\x6C\x73\x7C\x6B\x65\x79\x7C\x50\x4F\x53\x54\x7C\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73\x7C\x6F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x7C\x63\x61\x72\x74\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x7C\x76\x65\x72\x73\x69\x6F\x6E\x73\x7C\x6D\x65\x74\x68\x6F\x64\x7C\x6C\x6F\x67\x69\x6E\x7C\x6C\x69\x7C\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x7C\x69\x6E\x73\x74\x61\x6C\x6C\x5F\x75\x72\x6C\x7C\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72\x7C\x62\x6F\x6F\x6C\x7C\x74\x65\x78\x74\x7C\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x55\x52\x49\x43\x6F\x6D\x70\x6F\x6E\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x6D\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x72\x65\x69\x6E\x73\x74\x61\x6C\x6C\x7C\x63\x73\x73\x7C\x68\x74\x74\x70\x7C\x74\x6F\x4C\x6F\x77\x65\x72\x43\x61\x73\x65\x7C\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x62\x6C\x6F\x63\x6B\x65\x64\x7C\x6F\x62\x6A\x31\x7C\x70\x68\x70\x7C\x6F\x70\x61\x63\x69\x74\x79\x7C\x63\x69\x64\x7C\x70\x61\x73\x73\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x7C\x66\x61\x73\x74\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x5F\x63\x61\x74\x65\x67\x6F\x72\x79\x7C\x63\x61\x74\x63\x68\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x73\x6F\x6C\x65\x7C\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x7C\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x63\x61\x74\x65\x67\x6F\x72\x79\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x32\x7C\x74\x72\x75\x65\x7C\x6C\x6F\x67\x7C\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x5F\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x7C\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65\x7C\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65\x7C\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74\x7C\x7A\x69\x70\x7C\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x7C\x74\x79\x70\x65\x6F\x66\x7C\x74\x72\x79\x7C\x69\x73\x5F\x61\x72\x72\x61\x79\x7C\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x5F\x63\x61\x74\x65\x67\x6F\x72\x79\x7C\x69\x6E\x69\x74\x7C\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x55\x73\x65\x72\x50\x61\x63\x6B\x7C\x6D\x6F\x64\x75\x6C\x65\x73\x7C\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67\x69\x66\x79\x7C\x4A\x53\x4F\x4E\x7C\x70\x61\x63\x6B\x5F\x72\x65\x69\x6E\x73\x74\x61\x6C\x6C\x7C\x63\x61\x72\x74\x69\x6D\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x6D\x6F\x64\x75\x6C\x65\x7C\x73\x61\x76\x65\x75\x73\x65\x72\x7C\x63\x61\x72\x74\x7C\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73\x7C\x6E\x65\x77\x5F\x76\x65\x72\x73\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x63\x61\x74\x61\x6C\x6F\x67\x7C\x61\x6C\x6C\x63\x61\x74\x65\x67\x6F\x72\x79\x7C\x66\x61\x64\x65\x49\x6E\x7C\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x73\x7C\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74\x7C\x70\x61\x63\x6B\x5F\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x63\x75\x72\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x5F\x76\x65\x72\x73\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x7C\x76\x65\x72\x69\x66\x79\x75\x73\x65\x72\x7C\x63\x61\x74\x65\x67\x6F\x72\x69\x65\x73\x7C\x6C\x61\x6E\x67\x7C\x6C\x61\x6E\x67\x75\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x68\x6F\x73\x74\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66\x7C\x68\x33\x7C\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x7C\x70\x72\x6F\x70\x65\x72\x74\x79\x49\x73\x45\x6E\x75\x6D\x65\x72\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x7C\x73\x74\x6F\x72\x65\x5F\x73\x65\x61\x72\x63\x68\x7C\x61\x73\x73\x65\x74\x73\x7C\x6A\x75\x73\x74\x7C\x5F\x72\x65\x64\x75\x63\x65\x7C\x6C\x6F\x67\x69\x6E\x65\x64\x7C\x6C\x6F\x67\x6F\x75\x74\x7C\x76\x65\x72\x69\x66\x79\x7C\x73\x6E\x69\x70\x70\x65\x74\x73\x7C\x65\x6D\x70\x74\x79\x7C\x72\x65\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x7C\x76\x65\x72\x69\x66\x79\x55\x73\x65\x72\x7C\x65\x78\x69\x74\x75\x73\x65\x72\x7C\x73\x6C\x69\x63\x65\x7C\x33\x30\x30\x30\x7C\x6E\x75\x6D\x62\x65\x72\x7C\x6E\x6F\x6E\x65\x7C\x74\x70\x6C\x5F\x63\x61\x74\x65\x67\x6F\x72\x79\x32\x7C\x73\x65\x61\x72\x63\x68\x7C\x32\x30\x30\x30\x7C\x62\x6C\x6F\x63\x6B\x7C\x35\x30\x30\x7C\x64\x65\x6C\x61\x79\x7C\x63\x75\x72\x72\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x63\x6D\x73\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x7C\x64\x61\x74\x61\x54\x79\x70\x65\x7C\x65\x76\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x65\x78\x74\x72\x61\x73\x7C\x74\x70\x6C\x5F\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x7C\x74\x70\x6C\x5F\x7C\x74\x70\x6C\x5F\x63\x61\x74\x65\x67\x6F\x72\x79\x7C\x70\x61\x63\x6B\x5F\x69\x6E\x73\x74\x61\x6C\x6C\x7C\x67\x69\x74\x68\x75\x62\x7C\x72\x65\x64\x75\x63\x65\x7C\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x70\x72\x6F\x70\x7C\x69\x74\x65\x6D\x5F\x68\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72\x7C\x77\x72\x61\x70\x41\x6C\x6C\x7C\x6A\x73\x6F\x6E\x7C\x69\x6E\x73\x74\x61\x6C\x6C\x32\x7C\x72\x6F\x77\x7C\x73\x6E\x69\x70\x70\x65\x74\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x66\x69\x72\x6D\x7C\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x7C\x6F\x70\x65\x6E\x7C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x66\x69\x65\x6C\x64\x56\x61\x6C\x75\x65\x7C\x69\x73\x50\x6C\x61\x69\x6E\x4F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x7C\x66\x61\x6E\x63\x79\x62\x6F\x78\x7C\x70\x61\x63\x6B\x61\x67\x65\x7C\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x7C\x63\x68\x61\x6E\x67\x65\x7C\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x65\x72","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];eval(function (_0x1f4bx1,_0x1f4bx2,_0x1f4bx3,_0x1f4bx4,_0x1f4bx5,_0x1f4bx6){_0x1f4bx5=function (_0x1f4bx3){return (_0x1f4bx3<_0x1f4bx2?_0x191a[4]:_0x1f4bx5(parseInt(_0x1f4bx3/_0x1f4bx2)))+((_0x1f4bx3=_0x1f4bx3%_0x1f4bx2)>35?String[_0x191a[5]](_0x1f4bx3+29):_0x1f4bx3.toString(36));} ;if(!_0x191a[4][_0x191a[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0x1f4bx3--){_0x1f4bx6[_0x1f4bx5(_0x1f4bx3)]=_0x1f4bx4[_0x1f4bx3]||_0x1f4bx5(_0x1f4bx3);} ;_0x1f4bx4=[function (_0x1f4bx5){return _0x1f4bx6[_0x1f4bx5];} ];_0x1f4bx5=function (){return _0x191a[7];} ;_0x1f4bx3=1;} ;while(_0x1f4bx3--){if(_0x1f4bx4[_0x1f4bx3]){_0x1f4bx1=_0x1f4bx1[_0x191a[6]]( new RegExp(_0x191a[8]+_0x1f4bx5(_0x1f4bx3)+_0x191a[8],_0x191a[9]),_0x1f4bx4[_0x1f4bx3]);} ;} ;return _0x1f4bx1;} (_0x191a[0],62,228,_0x191a[3][_0x191a[2]](_0x191a[1]),0,{}));
```

Comment: Тяжело вытащить что-то из этого, но кажется это `XSS`. Может рекламу вам вставляют, может посетителей крадут.

Comment: http://deobfuscatejavascript.com/#

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Жаль не хватает репутации для плюса.